# How can I export Image as 3DL or Cube File?

Tags: swift, filter, save, lookup, cube

I'm using a png filter to filter a video/image but at the end I want the user to have export options.

So save video as mp4, photo as jpg/png etc

But I also need the user to save the filtered file as a 3DL and Cube file

Basically, 3DL files are used as LUTS/lookuptables in Adobe Premiere and Cube files are used as LUTS in DaVinci Resolve and FCPX.

But cube files also use two different sizes, 17x17x17 for FCPX and 33X33X33 for Resolve.

Any ideas how to save as 3dl and cube files?

Using Swift